# How to retrieve parent groups in Google using OAuth?

Tags: google-groups, oauth

Google gives the ability to add a group to another group.

For example, if we add Group A to Group B and user xyz@abc.com is present under Group A, and when I try to retrieve the groups of the user xyz@abc.com using OAuth 2.0 using the API https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups, it returns only Group A, and not Group B.

I would like to get Group B too in the response from Google, since Group A is a part of Group B.

Is there any way to do this? Does Google provide us with the list of all parent groups as well in OAuth?